# upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 12.10 (lower graphics mode)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, ati, graphics, 12.10

I just upgraded my 12.04 based Dell Inspiron laptop to 12.10 but after the reboot I got a message saying `system is running in lower graphics mode`. But I'm still not able to access Unity and GNOME. This is with an AMD Radeon HD 7570M graphics card. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and was getting the same error, so I found this thread and only run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg 
sudo reboot
```

For now this was my solution, hope this help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to go to console and remove the fglrx driver while in low graphic mode  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and  login with your user name and password then run

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglRx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo reboot
```

and also i would recommend to reinstall ubuntu desktop with this command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` Maybe it will help.

Comment: hi I tried it just now, I was not able to see the UI still hanging out in console. Any other fix?

Comment: so you removed the fglrx driver and rebooted and still get nothing am i right? Try to reinstall open drivers by executing :sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa ,sudo apt-get update , sudo apt-get upgrade ,sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg , sudo reboot

Comment: let me try this and get back to you then

Comment: Its not working, after the reboot I got the tty itself.

Comment: As a final try i would install 3.2.32 kernel via console to see if its fglrx problem cause 12.10 release has grapfic issues (some drivers dont work).3.2.32 kernel works 100 % with fglrx package by default in 12.04 lts. Then id try to install fglrx in console and boot 3.2.32 kernel(advanced option in grub). But all this optional cause it s only my guess that issue is in new kernel version 3.5.4 wich means you have to remove fglrx first to use it because the first rule before installing latest kernel vercion is to remove fglrx proprietary drivers or else it will be black screen.

Comment: Its quite complicated I guess reinstalling 12.04 will do

Comment: i just ran "startx" its says unable to connect Xorg server, whats the problem

Comment: To download kernel copy this in console: wget -c kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.3-precise/linux-headers-3.3.0-030300-generic_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_amd64.deb kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline//v3.3-precise/linux-headers-3.3.0-030300_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_all.deb kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline//v3.3-precise/linux-image-3.3.0-030300-generic_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_amd64.deb   030300.201203182135_amd64.deb continue to  next comment( limit of characters)

Comment: then after all downloaded copy: sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.3.0-030300-generic_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_amd64.deb linux-headers-3.3.0-030300_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_all.deb linux-image-3.3.0-030300-generic_3.3.0-030300.201203182135_amd64.deb after that install fglrx: sudo apt-get install fglrx then reconfigure xorg by: sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg then sudo reboot & do not forget to chose 3.3 kernel version in advanced grub menu.Hope it will work

Comment: @polarkatenuchie Instead of making multiple over-limit comments, I would *edit your post* to add these details.

Comment: tnx..installing kernel  is optional as it just my thoughts on this issue

Comment: Its not working too !!! I dont want to reinstall the ubuntu I am trying to fix this itself so that I can figure out and help ppl to fix the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For Intel integrated graphics on Core processors, it seems that lightdm is the culprit and workarounds are add a delay in rc.local or install and use gdm. [Launchpad seems to think that lightdm is too fast](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1070150?comments=all) at querying for a display and people are saying SSDs can contribute to this race condition. Not sure if this would help you.