# Low graphics error unless I boot via recovery mode

Tags: boot, login, recovery-mode

I recently upgraded to 12.10 (fresh install). I am a facing weird problem:

When I boot, I get a message notifying me of low graphics. For now, I have been switching to console using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then rebooting.

Upon reboot, I select recovery mode, allow system to boot and then again reboot.

Now I select normal mode and my graphics load smoothly.

Could you please tell me what could be the issue? I have a Dell Inspiron 5230 with Intel 4000 onboard graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has absolutely nothing to do with the GPU. It's a problem with LightDM and SSDs (or some other "abnormally fast" piece of hardware, Nvidia cards cause the same issue)

Try adding

```
respawn
```

below

```
stop on runlevel
```

In /etc/init/lightdm.conf

Often times, if you run into this error, you can hit

[Ctrl] + [Alt] + [5] to enter a terminal. Login and try

```
sudo lightdm start
```

If that doesn't yield anything try

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

As a side note, my SATAIII SSD was connected to the SATAII port on my logic board when I ran into this issue. Verify that your main SSD is on the correct port before you try anything.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I have a SSD (SATAIII connected to SATAII port) + NVIDIA GPU , and I had this very annoying problem, and had to reboot several times before the GUI showed up (sometimes it booted into the command line, but recently that "low graphics" thing has been showing up instead). That "respawn" command worked wonders, I never had the problem again. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Your question appears similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) although you mention you have an Intel GPU (it could be unrelated).

Basically, it looks like LightDM (the default greeter/login screen) can sometimes get a bit confused if you've installed other packages or something has gone wrong with its configuration.

Here is a relevant bug report, though possibly for a different version:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/971891

I think the best (least destructive) advice there is the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity-greeter
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Hopefully that should fix it!

You could also make sure that the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage is installed.

Some of the advice in that other question seems suspect to me, either because it involves installing random PPAs or it simply doesn't apply to people with Intel graphics.

Comment: I do not have any PPA installed, still it sometimes goes to low graphics mode. I will do reconfigure and let you know if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I gave this same answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204750). If this situation applies to you, these seem good workarounds.

For Intel integrated graphics on Core processors, it seems that lightdm is the culprit and workarounds are add a delay in rc.local or install and use gdm. [Launchpad seems to think that lightdm is too fast](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1070150?comments=all) at querying for a display and people are saying SSDs can contribute to this race condition. Not sure if this would help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try going into system settings, and under the "Additional Drivers" section, click on that. Their might possibly be an available driver for the card. I would use the recommended driver if any. That makes my graphics really smooth. Good luck!

Comment: It says no proprietary drivers are in use. I have intel 4000 graphics card.

Comment: It must be 12.10. I upgraded my laptop to that, and an hour later i was back to 12.04. I find that 12.04 works best.

Comment: OP said he has an Intel GPU.  Proprietary drivers are not applicable.